# There is no handler to execute for command

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I've been trying to build my first eclipse plugin where I can select a bit of text and then move it to the left or right with alt+left and alt+right. If I launch my plugin as an eclipse application, everything works fine and my plugin works. However, when I export my plugin as a deployable plugin with the destination as "Install into host" and run the command, sometimes I'll get `There is no handler to execute for command sirolf2009-eclipse-tools.commands.MoveSelectionLeft`. Other times I'll get

```
Exception occured when loading the handler
Plug-in sirolf2009-eclipse-tools was unable to load class com.sirolf2009.eclipsetools.handlers.MoveSelectionLeft.
com.sirolf2009.eclipsetools.handlers.MoveSelectionLeft cannot be found by sirolf2009-eclipse-tools_0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
```

I tried checking the jar that was generated during the export and it contains a class at the right location. I've uploaded the jar [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CCUhvFeTQ56SqeT9qLhkJ9FKbIqtJ4bi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't see the immediate problem but the jar is a mess. You have code in a `bin` directory - which won't be used. You have a `fragment.e4xmi` which also won't be used. I suggest you clean it all up. Also make sure you increment the version number every time you do 'install into host' to make sure Eclipse sees it is a new version.

Comment: The mess came from me trying to figure out the problem, I cleaned up, changed the version number and it worked. I'm guessing it was the version number as I never changed that. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to increment the version number (`Bundle-Version`) in the MANIFEST.MF each time you install in to Eclipse so that it knows the plug-in is new.

You can change any of the first 3 parts of the number, the 4th part is not checked.